# US Representatives salary & expenses without being sworn in (no Speaker)

Tags: united-states, house-of-representatives, public-sector-compensation

It is my understanding ([BBC Summary](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-64168529)), that the the first order of business for the US House of Representatives, is to appoint the Speaker. After this, the Representatives are sworn in.

Before being sworn in, can the Representatives-elect draw their salary, and claim expenses for their office and staffers? If they can't, it might concentrate their minds onto the task-in-hand a bit.

Comment: They do appear to be concentrating on their task of electing a speaker and personally the idea of tying a paycheck to the vote sounds like bribery/blackmail. There are plenty of members who can't afford to live without a paycheck and this sounds like forcing them to make a choice they do not want to in order to have the money they need to survive.

Comment: From what I've read, the Representatives are paid a salary that apparently is not in jeopardy. However, their staff's salaries may be in jeopardy if a Speaker isn't elected by Friday, January 13. That Friday is when the salary-based paychecks for staff should be issued, but doing so requires the House passing the rules of the House, and that in turn requires having a Speaker. https://www.politico.com/news/2022/12/29/house-committee-staff-pay-speaker-decision-00075801

Comment: @joew this is absurd. It's their job to elect a constitutionally required position; their paychecks are tied to them doing their job. And in every single congress the minority party largey doesn't vote for the winner so no one is making a vote for someone they don't want. In fact, the only reason the house is in the situation is because no one is voting for people they don't want...

Comment: @uberhaxed Regardless of it being their job they should not be pressured to change their votes like that because the leadership is unable to make a deal that they like. Instead of trying to get the same person elected to the position of speaker maybe they should consider other people who might be able to get the needed votes. If someone isn't getting more votes then the minority party after 11 votes maybe it is time to look for a compromise candidate.  As it stands now they are trying the same person again and it looks like the 13th vote will not work.

Comment: @Joew you realize the same can be said about the minority party (democrats in this case)? They also failed to elect a speaker after 11 votes.

Comment: @uberhaxed The minority party is not responsible for the majority party putting the same person up for vote 13 times and expect the vote count to suddenly change and elect someone. The majority party has the ability to either work out  a deal in the two months before the election was set to take place or work to find a different candidate who could get enough votes to get the speakers position. As it stands all members are working it is just that they can't agree on who should be the speaker. And it doesn't appear that more votes will get McCarthy into the position.

Comment: @JoeW When you talk about them having the money to survive, is that including just their salary or is it also including bribes?

Comment: @user253751 we don’t need to get into that area of accusations here.

Comment: @JoeW I think it's well established, and not merely an accusation, that representatives make millions of dollars "on the side" of their relatively meager salary. At best you can argue that such income does not qualify as "bribes" - not that it doesn't exist.

Comment: @user253751 It is not well established that they are taking bribes and if you have such evidence it should be investigated. Also this does not apply to all members of congress especially the newer ones. And I never said anything about the existence of such just the accusations of calling it bribes.

Comment: @joew the vote count does change regularly, and moreover the minority has the option to vote for a candidate that will get some votes from the other party. Obviously, party loyalty is not so important to Republicans as it is the Democrats, so they don't vote as a block.

Comment: @uberhaxed Correct, and the majority also has the option to nominate someone else who might be able to convince either the hold outs or members of the minority to cast their votes for them. The issue isn't just the people not voting for who the majority wants but the majority for refusing to consider making a change. Nominating the same people over and over again and expecting change is crazy.

Comment: @Joew the reason the vote tally changes is because the candidates are campaigning and promising procedural changes to the hold outs. It's neither correct to say that change is not occurring (votes literally change between elections) and the platform they are running on is the same.

Comment: @uberhaxed And that change didn’t happen until the 12th vote which was after this question was asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Before being sworn in, can the Representatives-elect draw their
> salary, and claim expenses for their office and staffers?

[Current practice](https://www.politico.com/news/2022/12/29/house-committee-staff-pay-speaker-decision-00075801) is that Representatives-elect get paid anyway, but they can't claim expenses for their offices and the staffers don't get paid until the Speaker is selected.

Comment: I would expect that those staffers would be paid after the fact. Typically, civil servants and contractor employees who had to keep working as essential workers during a government shutdown are given back pay after the debacle is over.